# Softlayer Python API:multiple local properties of billing item are not returned

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Calling the billing_Item Python API, a billing_item is returned BUT a lot of (interesting) local properties are not returned. The local properties of my interest all have to do with uptime and fees (e.g. laborFee, oneTimeFee, hoursUsed, recurringFee, ...), but they are not returned.

What I do:

```
import SoftLayer

conn = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username='',api_key='')

allParents = conn.call('Account','getAllTopLevelBillingItems') #allParents is a list with billing_Items

allParents[0] # returns the first billing_Item as a dict but without a lot of relevant parameters
```

Also, the children billing items of each parent billing item lack a lot of local properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an issue with your account. I suggest you try a simple Rest Call like this:

```
https://$Username:$Apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getAllTopLevelBillingItems
Repalce $Username and $Apikey
```

If you get the same issue. Report it by opening a ticket in the Softlayer´s Portal in order the Softlayer guys take a look at this

Comment: Problem is solved! I didn't have some (necessary) permissions to see the some of the other local properties. The administrator can set these permissions at the controlplane of softlayer

Answer (score 1):

The below python script displays the local properties that you need. Also, if your script doesn't return the properties that you need, please apply object masks, like this example:

```
import SoftLayer
# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

apiUsername = 'set me'
apiKey = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=apiUsername,
    api_key=apiKey
)

objectMask = 'mask[id,laborFee,oneTimeFee,recurringFee]'

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getAllTopLevelBillingItems(mask=objectMask)
    pp(result)
except Exception as e:
    pp('Failed ............', e)
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: With you suggestions/code, the result is still ONLY the 'id' and no variables as 'laborFee',oneTimeFee' and 'recurringFee' are still missing...

Comment: This issue is something strange. In my case I was able to see these properties even if the script doesn't apply the masks. Maybe it is a user permissions problem. Could you try the script using a "Master Account" please?